# What is the meaning of the phrase "that work forces" in Rage Against the Machine song Killing In The Name Of?

Tags: phrase-meaning

The first verse of the song “Killing In The Name Of” by Rage Against the Machine is:

> Some of those that work forces,
> are the same that burn crosses

What is the meaning of the phrase "that work forces"? How are these words grammatically structured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grammar is a bit convoluted to make it fit rhythm and rhyme, as is common in lyrics and poetry.

The entire first line, “Some of those that work forces”, is the subject of the verb “are” in the second line.

“that work forces” is a restrictive relative clause modifying “those”, which in turn is part of a prepositional phrase modifying “some”.

“forces” refers to *police* forces (this requires outside knowledge), so the first line is a complicated way of saying “some cops”.

The second line says that these cops are members of the KKK.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the structure of "that work forces"? What is the verb here?

Comment: @nofatigua Edited to explain the grammar more. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: So if "forces" means police, what "work" means here? Some of those that work in the forces?

Comment: @nofatigua “those that work in/at/for police forces”, where “work” refers to their job. They’re cops.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this lyric isn't what Zack de la Rocha sang. I think he sang;
Some of those that work for us is
Are the same that burn crosses

Comment: Not a definitive evidence, but their official YouTube disagrees: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWXazVhlyxQ